# Xamarin studio for windows issue: framework not installed .NETPortable profile 136

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio

I want to develop android version of my app using xamarin studio for windows. Previously I was using it on Mac. The problem is that when I open solution on windows machine, all portable projects can't be buil due to problems with refferenced portable subset. "Framework not installed .NETPortable profile 136" is displayed in a references trey. Following tools are installed: Mono for Windows 3.2.3; MDK 3.4; Xamarin.Android 4.12.4; PortableLibraryTools for VS 2010.

Comment: Do you have version 2 of the Portable Library Tools for VS2010 from the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/)? I am pretty sure it will not work with the older version.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Portable library tools 2 is installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Profile136 is included in the [Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40727). The Portable Library Tools 2 does not include this profile.

The Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6 download installs a zip file into

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6\PortableReferenceAssemblies.zip
```

which you will need to unzip and extract the contents into the directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable
```

After that you will need to reinstall Xamarin.Android so these profiles have the Xamarin.Android profiles added to them.

Comment: I have the same problem, but this solution doesn't work for me